# How to set the right click menu popped out after the right click being done in GNOME 3

Tags: mouse, gnome-shell, menu, context-menu

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and GNOME 3 and I found that different from
Windows. When I press the right mouse button, the right click menu gets 
out. After I release that button, if the mouse pointer is on any menu item, that item will be choose which is not I want.

I want to know how to set the menu popped out after the right-click being done (when releasing the right mouse button).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my system (18.10). When I right-click, the menu remains popped out and I have to effectively click somewhere to close it, or click on a menu item to execute it.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Immediately release the right-click button before moving the mouse cursor, and the menu will stay. If you drag the pointer while the mouse button is held, a release will trigger a choice or close the menu. That is actually more efficient than in Windows, where you apparently need multiple clicks in all cases. Duplicate question is about that. No, you cannot change that.